# How to refresh pivot table excel Using ClosedXML and C#

Tags: pivot-table, closedxml

I am trying to refresh pivot table using C# and CLosedXml dll.

I have source data which is dynamically updated from database. I have pivot table template which gets changed based upon the data in source destination. It works perfectly when I am trying manually.

Now I need to refresh the pivot table through programming language (i.e. C#) and closedXML.

Can anyone please help me on this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Do you have code showing how you tried to solve this, or started to?

Answer (score 0):

Pivot table rendering is not supported in ClosedXML yet. The pivot table should refresh/render when you open the file in Excel though.